# TortoiseSVN context menu whitelist

Tags: windows-7, tortoisesvn, contextmenu

In tortoiseSvn there is an option to create a list, where the context menu is not shown
(Settings -> General -> Context menu -> "Do not show the context menu for the following paths:")

But is there a possibility to make this "blacklist" into a "whitelist"

e.a. list the paths, where i want the context menu to be shown?

running win7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the UI and documentation, this does not appear to be possible at the moment.

You can read [here](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/wiki/IssueTracker?tm=3) about submitting an issue for the TSVN team to consider.